# Start Jersey application with Jetty

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, ubuntu-12.04

I install jetty 9 server in my Ubuntu server VCS. Structure of java rest project:

/opt/jetty/webapps/backend /

- build
- conf
- lib
- libs
- logs
- src/com/example/package/backend

  - resources

    - CategoryResource.java
  - BackendServer.java
- web

  - WEB-INF

    - web.xml

BackendServer.java

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class BackendServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:" + "8080" + "/" + "backend/rest", new PackagesResourceConfig("com.droidbrew.androcommerce.backend.resources"));
        DbManager.getInstance();
        server.start();

        System.out.println("Server running");
        System.out.println("Hit return to stop...");
        System.in.read();
        System.out.println("Stopping server");
        server.stop(0);
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
    }
}
```

CategoryResource.java

```
Path("/category")
public class CategoryResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/get_all_categories")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String getAllCategories() throws SQLException {
        List<Category> categoryList = DbManager.getInstance().getBackendCategoryManager().getAllCategories();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(categoryList);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Jersey</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
          <param-value>com.droidbrew.androcommerce.backend.resources</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

/opt/jetty/webapps/backend.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="configurationClasses">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
              <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
              <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
              <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration</Item>
              <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
              <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
            </Array>
    </Set>
    <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
    <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/backend</Set>

    <New id="development" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
            <Arg>jdbc/development</Arg>
            <Arg>
                    <New class="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource">
                            <Set name="User">user</Set>
                            <Set name="Password">1111</Set>
                            <Set name="DatabaseName">development</Set>
                            <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
                            <Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set>
                    </New>
            </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

But after I start `service jetty start` and try connect `ip:8085/backend/rest/category/get_all_categories` I get:

*HTTP ERROR: 404*

*Problem accessing* /backend/rest/category/get_all_categories. *Reason*:

*Not Found*

**UPDATE**
Logs after `java -DDEBUG -jar start.jar`

```
sudo java -DDEBUG -jar start.jar
System Property [DEBUG] has been deprecated! (Use org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG instead)
2014-10-06 13:09:09.522:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1090ms
ShutdownMonitor not in use (port < 0): -1
2014-10-06 13:09:10.047:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.3.v20140905
2014-10-06 13:09:10.073:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:/opt/jetty/webapps/] at interval 1
2014-10-06 13:09:10.096:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:main: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.createContextHandler(WebAppProvider.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App.getContextHandler(App.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
2014-10-06 13:09:10.111:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED ServerConnector@1d402894{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
2014-10-06 13:09:10.114:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5f281b8c: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:111)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML files are referencing an old version of Jetty.

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
```

The `org.mortbay.jetty` namespace is for Jetty 6 or older versions of Jetty, (all of which have been EOLd for years now).

That entire XML document is wrong for Jetty 9, from the DOCTYPE, to the class references, even to the structure.

The `<SystemProperty>` element references a `"jetty.home"` variable that isn't used in jetty embedded (its only there for the jetty distribution, aka start.jar).  The `jetty-http-spi.jar` doesn't even set or use this property.

The use of the Jetty Context XML Deployable is a feature that `jetty-deploy.jar` provides, however, that sort of deployable is not supported by the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` concepts, either as a standalone deployable, or an internal `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` configuration.

That whole backend server war you are attempting to setup just cannot be on the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` you started (not supported by that concept at a fundamental level)

Unfortunately, there is almost no troubleshooting available when you use the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` techniques. Pretty much limited to logging output.

What does the logging output show?

**Update: 2014, Oct 7:**

About the logging output, lets see.

You are starting jetty via command line, using the Jetty 9.2.3 distribution.

That act is completely unrelated to your `BackendServer` use of `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`.

This would result in 2 different servers.

1. The standalone Jetty 9.2.3 distribution server
2. The `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` server

You have essentially 2 errors showing in those logs.

First is ...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
```

That's because you are using Jetty 6 techniques for Jetty 9.  That class (actually package namespace) doesn't exist in Jetty 9.

That class (in Jetty 9) would be called [`org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html), see [Configuring a Specific Web App Deployment](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.3.v20140905/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html) in the Eclipse Jetty documentation website for details.

You will have to analyze and adjust most things in your example XML file to fit the realities of the nearly 200 releases since Jetty 6 and Jetty 9. Far too much time has elapsed between Jetty 6 and Jetty 9 to list what has changed.  It would be equivalent to listing the differences between a Ford Model 18 and a Tesla Model S (it would be a huge list that would essentially mean 'everything' and be useless to work off of)

The other error ...

```
FAILED ServerConnector@1d402894{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

means that this server cannot bind to port 8080, as some other server is already there.

This makes sense, as your `BackendServer` is also on port 8080 (per your example code).

Don't try to mix embedded-jetty and `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`, you will only tear your hair out trying to force `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` into doing what you want.

Consider using straight embedded-jetty + jersey servlet instead.

There's lots of examples of this technique online and in StackOverflow.

Here's the first one I found that had example code showing how to setup the `ServletHolder` for the jersey `ServletContainer` along with some relevant init parameters to configure it. [Configuring Jersey + Jetty + JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339451/configuring-jersey-jetty-jsp)

Comment: I add logs. As I understand, I do everything wrong. Can you give me links for jetty 9 understandable tutorials?