# Start java application with jetty without WAR file

Tags: java, nginx, jersey, jetty, war

I try start Jersey + Jetty + Nginx via [this tutorial](http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers) and I cannot use war file. How can I start my java application?

I start application by right click on BackendServer.java and click "Run" in IDEA or using in terminal `java -cp /home/example/backend/build/WEB-INF/lib/backend.jar:/home/example/backend/libs/* com.example.backend.BackendServer`.

Project structure is described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218640/start-jersey-application-with-jetty/26219306)

/opt/jetty/webapps/backend.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC
    "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!--
  Configure a custom context for serving javadoc as static resources
-->

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>??????????</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>index.html</Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
      <Set name="cacheControl">max-age=3600,public</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

What should be instead `???????`? Should I use embedded jetty in BackendServer.java? I know that I have redirect requests from nginx to jetty, but I don't understand how can I start jersey application with jetty...

Answer (score 0):

The linked example/tutorial and the linked earlier question are not compatible.

The tutorial is for Jetty 6 (now impossibly out of date), and uses embedded-jetty completely, with deployments and everything enabled.

Your prior question sets up a `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` which is not the same thing.

`resourceBase` is the root directory for any webapp content that you might want to serve.

Since you are using a simple `ContextHandler`, then that should point to a directory on your disk.

If you were using a `WebAppContext`, then that should point to your webapp base directory (where optional files like `WEB-INF/web.xml` or `WEB-INF/classes` would be)

The `ResourceHandler` you have defined should use the `ContextHandler.resourceBase`.

Be aware that `ResourceHandler` is for the barest, most simplistic static file serving.
If you have any requirements from your web clients to perform cached lookups, resume downloads, partial downloads, or mime-type controls, then use a `DefaultServlet`.

Also, if all you want is a file server in embedded jetty, why are you using an XML deployment with a basic `ContextHandler`?  That would be so much easier to just write into your embedded jetty service.

Some embedded jetty example code that might prove useful to you:

- [Multiple DefaultServlet's in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207477/jetty-embedded-file-server-servlet/20223103#20223103).
- [Simple Servlet + DefaultServlet in embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26101463/jetty-chrome-freeze-the-video-after-first-playback/26148582#26148582) - shows why `ResourceHandler` isn't a good choice in some circumstances.
- [Embedded Jetty with JSP support](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp)
- [4 different ways to use WebSocket with Embedded Jetty](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples)
- [Embedded Jetty using WAR/WebAppContext supporting Servlet 3.0 features](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0)
- [Embedded Jetty using WAR/WebAppContext supporting Servlet 3.1 features](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.1)